# I need help in setting a mobile view for an angular website

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website for which I need help in fixing the mobile view for it. I have a menu which has 5 buttons in it. I am satisfied with the laptop/desktop view but not the mobile view.

In the mobile view I am having all the 5 buttons instead of the menu button. For example, My website looks similar to https://www.trujet.com (not all the functionalities but the menu)
I am including the code here:

```
<head>
  <title>Mywebsite</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a id="site-logo" href="#">
        <img src="assets/img/website.png">
      </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
  </button>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
  <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/" (click)="homec()" class="btn btn-primary">
            <h5>HOME</h5></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/aboutus" (click)="aboutusc()" class="btn btn-primary">
            <h5>ABOUT US</h5></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="dropdown">
              <button type="button" class="dropbtn"
              class="btn btn-primary"><h5>PACKAGES</h5></button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a routerLink="/eduinstitution" (click)="educac()" class="btn btn-primary"><h6>
                  EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTIONS</h6></a>
                <a routerLink="/international" (click)="interc()" class="btn btn-primary"><h6>
                  INTERNATIONAL</h6></a>
                <a routerLink="/domestic" (click)="domesc()" class="btn btn-primary"><h6>
                  DOMESTIC</h6></a>
                <a routerLink="/honeymoon" (click)="honeyc()" class="btn btn-primary"><h6>
                  HONEYMOON</h6></a>
                </div>
              </div>
      </li>    
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/gallery" (click)="galleryc()" class="btn btn-primary">
            <h5>GALLERY</h5></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/contactus" (click)="contactus()" class="btn btn-primary">
            <h5>CONTACT US</h5></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">Mywebsite@gmail.com |  </span>
            <span class="contact-phone small">+91 xxxxxxxxxx</span>
    </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/website"><img src="assets/img/fb.png"></a> 
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the hamburger menu it doesn't display the menu(Home,Contact us,etc). In short, Bootstrap - Navbar Collapse menu not displaying.

Comment: You can use a burger menu. That way all the navigation will be inside of it.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can help here. What code are you using to render your buttons?

Comment: Try :- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, I am using bootstrap here to display the menus, the problem is it displays all the buttons in the computer view but for the mobile view it has to display a single menu but it isn't. For example in the website(https://www.trujet.com) it will display plan manage fly offers in the desktop view, if you toggle it to mobile view and click sandwich button then it will display all the (plan manage fly offers) menus. which is not happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using Angular you can take advantage of RxJS and use Angular's BreakpointObserver which is included in `@angular/cdk/layout`. If you google examples of BreakpointObserver you'll find much more information than we can give you in a Stack Overflow Q&A.

I'd suggest that you try and follow a breakpoint observer tutorial, then if there's something in your code that doesn't work as expected come back to StackOverflow and ask for help regarding that specific example. Your current question is not technically suited for StackOverflow since it doesn't provide any examples of code that you have already tried.

In shorter words, we can't help you because the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span style="color: yellow">Website</span></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a routerLink="/" (click)="home()">
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                <span style="color: yellow">
                  <h4>HOME</h4>
                </span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/aboutus" (click)="aboutus()">
                <span style="color:yellow">
                  <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
                </span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span style="color:yellow">
                  <h4>DROPDOWN</h4>
                </span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a routerLink="/expresscar" (click)="cexpcs()"><span style="color:yellow">
                      <h6>
                        SUB-MENU1</h6>
                    </span></a>
            <a routerLink="/permaiser" (click)="cpemas()"><span style="color:yellow">
                      <h6>
                        SUB-MENU2</h6>
                    </span></a>


          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
              <a routerLink="/faqs" (click)="faqscl()">
                <span style="color:yellow">
                  <h4>FAQ's</h4>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
              <a routerLink="/gallery" (click)="gallery()"><span style="color:yellow">
                  <h4>GALLERY</h4>
                </span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a routerLink="/contact" (click)="contactus()"><span style="color:yellow">
                  <h4>CONTACT US</h4>
                </span></a>
            </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </nav>
  </div>
```

It worked for me in Angular 7 and Bootstrap, Thanks for all your help.